# Error initializing task Copy: Not registered task Copy

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am just getting started working in Xamarin. I am trying to join a group project hosted on GitHub. I have cloned the project and updated the submodules. The problem I am having is that when I build the project I get this error:

```
Error initializing task Copy: Not registered task Copy.
```

The others guys in my group haven't ever seen this problem and don't know what could be causing it. I have searched online for solutions to the problem. Most posts suggest updating Xamarin and/or Xcode - I have done both and am still getting the same error.  I am able to build the sample Xamarin projects and load them onto devices without problems. I am currently using a Community license while I determine if I am going to be a long term contributor to the project. The guys in my group have Enterprise licenses.

Below is my "about" information for Xamarin. I just updated to Mac Sierra OS yesterday.  I was seeing this problem before and after updating.

> Xamarin Studio Community Version 6.1.1 (build 15) Installation UUID:
>   94d3f999-f138-4164-8006-6daff97f9dcf Runtime:     Mono 4.6.1
>   (mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/abb06f1) (64-bit)    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh
>   theme)
>
> Package version: 406010003
>
> NuGet Version: 3.4.3.0
>
> Xamarin.Profiler Not Installed
>
> Apple Developer Tools Xcode 8.0 (11246) Build 8A218a
>
> Xamarin.Mac Version: 2.10.0.103 (Xamarin Studio Community)
>
> Xamarin.Android Version: 7.0.1.2 (Xamarin Studio Community) Android
>   SDK:
>   /Users/ryan.tensmeyer/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
>     Supported Android versions:
>         4.0.3  (API level 15)
>         4.4    (API level 19)
>         4.4.87 (API level 20)
>         5.0    (API level 21)
>         5.1    (API level 22)
>         6.0    (API level 23)
>         7.0    (API level 24)
>
> SDK Tools Version: 25.2.2 SDK Platform Tools Version: 24.0.3 SDK Build
>   Tools Version: 24.0.2
>
> Java SDK: /usr java version "1.8.0_102" Java(TM) SE Runtime
>   Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
>
> Android Designer EPL code available here:
>   https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL
>
> Xamarin Android Player Not Installed
>
> Xamarin.iOS Version: 10.0.1.8 (Xamarin Studio Community) Hash: 3983064
>   Branch: cycle8-sr0-xi Build date: 2016-09-23 15:34:54-0400
>
> Build Information Release ID: 601010015 Git revision:
>   fa52f02641726146e2589ed86ec4097fbe101888 Build date: 2016-09-22
>   08:03:02-04 Xamarin addins: 75d65712af93d54dc39ae4c42b21dfa574859fd6
>   Build lane: monodevelop-lion-cycle8-sr0
>
> Operating System Mac OS X 10.12.0 Darwin j76502.iconfitness.com 16.0.0
>   Darwin Kernel Version 16.0.0
>       Mon Aug 29 17:56:20 PDT 2016
>       root:xnu-3789.1.32~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Can someone help me resolve this error?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project? Can you try enable diagnostic build output and provide that? Does this happen for both iOS and Android projects, or just one of the project types?

Comment: I have cleaned the project and the result doesn't change. I believe this happens for both iOS and Android projects. I enabled the diagnostic build output and I was going to post it, but it's over 1300 pages when pasted into a Google Doc (apparently too large to save and share). The next comment shows the text from the build output that I believe to be pertinent.

Comment: Xamarin.iOS.Tasks, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: error : Error executing task DetectSdkLocations: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.
  Error executing task DetectSdkLocations: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Xamarin.MacDev, Version=1.0.5969.31769, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.Execute () .......

Comment: As another note, after multiple cleans/builds my error has changed to: Error executing task DetectSdkLocations: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.

Comment: Have you started Xcode and accepted the license agreement?

Comment: Yes, I have started Xcode and accepted the license agreement.